# javascript no effect on dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a aspx file which run some javascript. It work fine when I opened it by using window.showModalDialog. However it didn't work on Chrome, so I opened it in dialog by using jquery. The page is loaded into dialog, but the javascript function has no effect.  Would some one tell me how to solve the problem?

There is my javascript :

```
function checkAll(rptrName, linkButtonId) {
    var select;
    var iNumElems = document.forms[0].elements.length;
    var link = document.getElementById(linkButtonId)

    if (link.innerHTML.indexOf('Select') == 0) {
       select = true;
       link.innerHTML = "Clear All"
    } else {
       select = false;
       link.innerHTML = "Select All"
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < iNumElems; i++) {
        var oElem = document.forms[0].elements[i];
        if ("checkbox" == oElem.type) {
            if (oElem.name.indexOf(rptrName) == 0) {
                oElem.checked = select
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is the function I opened it by dialog

```
function openDialog(url) {

$("#dialog-box").load(url).dialog({
    id:'location',
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: 600,
    width: 600,
    modal: true
});

$('#dialog-box').dialog('open');
     return false;
}
```

There is the HTML code on parent page:

```
<div id="dialog-box" title=" "></div>

<td width="43%" align="right">
    <asp:button 
         id="btnSelect" 
         runat="server" 
         causesvalidation="False" text="Select Locations"
         OnClientClick="javascript:return openDialog('popLocation.aspx');" />
</td>
```

There is the code to call checkAll function

```
Dim pnlRegion As New Panel
            pnlRegion.CssClass = "gridRegion"

            Dim chklRegion As New CheckBoxList
            chklRegion.BorderWidth = Unit.Point(1)
            chklRegion.CellPadding = 2
            chklRegion.RepeatColumns = 3
            chklRegion.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
            chklRegion.ID = "chkl" & objR.Value

            myObject.ui.webForms.objBind(chklRegion, objRegionLocations, "Name", "LocationId")

            checkOff(chklRegion)

            ' add select all link
            Dim hypSelectAll As New HyperLink
            hypSelectAll.ID = "hyp" & objR.Value
            hypSelectAll.NavigateUrl = "javascript://"
            hypSelectAll.Text = "Select All"
            hypSelectAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkAll('" & chklRegion.ClientID & "','" & hypSelectAll.ClientID & "');return false;")

            ' add title, select all, then checkboxlis
            pnlRegion.Controls.Add(lblRegion)
            pnlRegion.Controls.Add(hypSelectAll)
            pnlRegion.Controls.Add(chklRegion)

            ' add panel to placeholder
            plcRegions.Controls.Add(pnlRegion)
```

Comment: What JavaScript function isn't working? The checkAll() function? Could we see the HTML of the page that's loaded into the dialog?

Comment: @BurningLights I added the html code.

Comment: you are not calling this `checkAll()` function anywhere in your script.

Comment: OnClientClick is a webview control, not a standard html/js one

Comment: I debugged the javascript. it shown that it didn't get any checkbox.